# APNS - Is it possible to push MDM profiled devices through the HTTP/2 based API?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm, http2

Till today, I pushed my devices through the "Binary Provider API", which is now marked as legacy. So I started to implement the new HTTP/2 based API, but I'm unable to make it work. Now, before I put any more effort into it, I'd like to know, if it is possible at all, to push MDM profiled devices thorugh the new API, since it is not mentioned anywhere, that this API supports MDM related topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the HTTP/2 API works fine for MDM.

Comment: Do you know, if it works with provider tokens, instead of  certificates? This would be very comforting, since push requests to different topics could all be done through one socket.

Comment: I'm only familiar with using the MDM certificate issued by Apple.

Comment: @tsfrank which client are you using? I'm trying to implement using pushy and I'm having issues with that, previously I had a notnoop implementation working like a charm, but like Norman I want to update the client.